# why my div is not hidden

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

What i try to do here is everytime when I click button. It should hide the div name review and show  the div name comment. But now it's not working. It wont hide or show anything.

Here is my cmp file

```
  <div class="slds-box small" aura:id="main">
    <div aura:id="panelList">
      <header>
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--small">In the Area</h2>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-assistive-text" for="searchBox">Search</label>
          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
              <ui:inputText aura:id="searchTerm" label="" class="field" placeholder="Search for..." change="{!c.updateSearch}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <p class="slds-hide" aura:id="warning">{!v.errorMessage}</p>
      <div class="slds-scrollable--y scroll-container" aura:id="scrollableArea">
      <ul class="slds-list--vertical slds-has-dividers--top-space">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.restaurantList}" var="item" indexVar="i">
            <li class="slds-list__item" onclick="{!c.showDetails}" data-record="{!i}">
                <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--x-small">{!item.name}</h3>
                <img src="{!item.ratingImg}" alt="" class="ratingStars" />
               <div class="slds-hide" data-details="{!i}">
               <ul class="slds-list--vertical">
                   <li class="slds-list__item">{!item.address}</li>
                   <li class="slds-list__item">{!item.city},{!item.state}</li>
                   <li class="slds-list__item">{!item.phone}</li>
               </ul>
              <div aura:id="review" class="slds-media slds-m-top--medium ">
                   <div class="slds-media__figure">
                       <img src="{!item.image}" class="slds-avatar--large slds-avatar--circle" alt="Placeholder" />
                   </div>
               <div class="slds-media__body">
               <p >{!item.review}</p>      
           </div>
          </div>
            <div aura:id="comment" class="slds-media__body slds-hide">
               <p >{!v.comments}</p>  
            </div>
               <ui:inputtextarea aura:id="comments"  label="Write Review:" class="slds-input" rows="2" value="{!v.comments}" />
               <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.resetReview}" />
              </div>
            </li>
        </aura:iteration>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="slds-spinner_container slds-hide" aura:id="spinner">
      <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
          <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
          <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

My controller

```
({

    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var main = component.find('main');
    var recID = component.get("v.recordId");
    if (recID) {
            $A.util.removeClass(main, 'small');
            $A.util.addClass(main, component.get("v.designHeight"));
            helper.getLocalList(component, recID);
    } else {
            $A.util.removeClass(main, 'small');
            $A.util.removeClass(main, component.get("v.designHeight"));
            $A.util.addClass(main, 'autoHeight');
            var scrollableArea = component.find('scrollableArea');
            $A.util.removeClass(scrollableArea, 'scroll-container');
            $A.util.removeClass(scrollableArea, 'slds-scrollable--y');
            var spinner = component.find('spinner');
            $A.util.removeClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
            component.set("v.location", e);
          }, function() {
                    component.set("v.errorMessage", "Could not get your current geolocation.");
                    var warning = component.find('warning');
                    $A.util.removeClass(warning, 'slds-hide');
          });
        }
    },

    updateSearch: function(component, event, helper) {
    var recID = component.get("v.recordId");
    helper.getLocalList(component, recID);
    },
    showDetails: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set()
        var closeItem = component.get('v.openItem');
        if (closeItem) {
            closeItem = closeItem.querySelector('[data-details]');
            $A.util.addClass(closeItem, 'slds-hide');
        }
        var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
        component.set('v.openItem', selectedItem);
        var itemDetails = selectedItem.querySelector('[data-details]')
        $A.util.removeClass(itemDetails, 'slds-hide');
    },
    resetReview: function(component, event, helper){
      var newReview = component.get("v.comments");
      var review = component.find("review");
      var comment = component.find("comment");
      console.log("This is my new review: ", newReview);
      $A.util.addClass(review, "slds-hide");
      $A.util.removeClass(comment, "slds-hide");     
}
})
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is there a typo on *component.find(“comments”)*, looks like there’s a **s** extra in there.

Comment: @JayantDas good eye. I completely missed it.

Comment: @sfdcfox this is a lesson learnt hard way with lightning/JS :). I always kind of take a microscope to see anything related to JS stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the provided code, your issue seems to be on this line 3 of your controller function where you are trying to retrieve the comment div it with an extra ***s*** in its id:

```
var comment = component.find('comments'); // notice the extra s here
```

whereas you have declared the id of the div on your component as below (without s as *comment*):

```
<div aura:id="comment" class="slds-media__body slds-hide">
```

Either you change the id in component or retrieve it in the JS by removing the extra ***s*** as:

```
var comment = component.find('comment'); // remove s from here
```

Additionally what you can use here is to dynamically toggle the class. For that purpose use `$A.util.toggleClass(cmp, "class")` to toggle visibility of markup. You can refer to more details on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm).

**Also a recommendation**, while using string literals in JS, try using double-quotes for consistency, e.g., `component.find("myid");` etc.

As an example, this is what I tried. Have two divs here and they are initially hidden and shown on click of submit button and hidden back on click of the other button.

```
<div aura:id="review" class="slds-media slds-m-top--medium slds-hide">
    <p>This is image section</p>
</div>

<div aura:id="comment" class="slds-media__body slds-hide">
    <p >This is comment section</p>  
</div>

<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.showAll}" />
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Hide Again" onclick="{!c.hideAll}" />


showAll: function(component, event, helper){
    var review = component.find("review");
    var comment = component.find("comment");

    $A.util.addClass(review, "slds-show");
    $A.util.removeClass(review, "slds-hide");

    $A.util.addClass(comment, "slds-show");
    $A.util.removeClass(review, "slds-hide");
},

hideAll: function(component, event, helper){
    var review = component.find("review");
    var comment = component.find("comment");

    $A.util.addClass(review, "slds-hide");
    $A.util.removeClass(review, "slds-show");

    $A.util.addClass(comment, "slds-hide");
    $A.util.removeClass(comment, "slds-show");
},
```

Comment: It still not working. I removed s  `var comment = component.find("comment");` and I also chenged `$A.util.removeClass(comment, "slds-hide");` , but still not showing anything

Comment: Though you don't have your complete code, but I can tell you this is working as I had this implemented in my personal DE. Also I added usage around *toggleClass*, which you could use to show/hide a markup. Remember, once your markup is hidden, you will need to toggle and bring it back for your other action. Once hidden it won't be shown until you really refresh your page.

Comment: I have now put all my code from cmp file and my controller. Please check if there is anything wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added the example I had tried, so you may like to take a cue from there. Also a recommendation is that try with minimum of what you want to achieve and then extend your code to other functionalities. That will give you more handle on your error handling.

Answer (score 0):

In resetReview method, replace the double quotes with single quote while setting css class.

```
resetReview: function(component, event, helper){
      var newReview = component.get("v.comments");
      var review = component.find("review");
      var comment = component.find("comment");
      console.log("This is my new review: ", newReview);
      $A.util.addClass(review, 'slds-hide');
      $A.util.removeClass(comment, 'slds-hide');     
}
```